# php cannot validate if fields are set

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

When I submit empty fields, it displays "Something has gone wrong" instead of "All fields are required.". Could you help me to find my mistake please.

**PHP file:**

```
<?php 
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) || 
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['order'])) {
$data = array(
         'message' => "All fields are required."                    
             );
    echo json_encode($data);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Wtf, you are sending post values and echoing only if post values are missing. So you are logically wrong aren't you?

Comment: I want to echo if at least one field is missing. It's the first step of validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You conditions in PHP file are wrong. Use this instead

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['order'])) {
    $data = array('message' => "Message A");
    echo json_encode($data);
}else{
    $data = array('message' => "All fields are required");
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

I use `&&` for required values. You can use `&&` or `||` according to your need.

**Update**

```
if(!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['order'])) {
    $data = array('message' => "All fields are required");
    echo json_encode($data);
}else{
    // whatever you want to do, if all values available, goes here
}
```

Comment: thanks man. but I want to send "all fields are required" message if at least one field is not set.

Comment: yes, but my problem is that when i submit empty fields it does not show me "All fields are required" message

Comment: `empty()` does two things. It not only checks if the key exists in `$_POST` or `$_GET` but it also checks if it contains a value or not, keep in mind that it considers 0 as empty. `isset()` only checks if the key exists.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['order'])) {
    echo "No post values found!";
}
else{
    $data = array('message' => "Message A");
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks. but my message A is "No post values found" :) so I cannot understand what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using !isset() try using empty().